# Как исправить формулу, которая работала в эксель и не работает в МойОфис Таблицы?

Tags: excel

У меня в эксель документе была формула, которая смотрела на диапазон значений и если буква, которая находилась рядом с цифрой, совпадала с нужно, то цифры суммировались. Например, в колонке I, напротив двух "8 у", должно быть число 16 (8 + 8).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Формула была следующая (для строки с "8 у, для других меняется число строки)":

`=СУММ(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСК("б"; B8:I8); --ПОДСТАВИТЬ(B8:I8; "б"; "")); 0))`

Подскажите, как переделать эту формулу, чтобы она заработала в МойОфис?

Comment: Где столбец I? Где строка 8? При чем тут даты? Ищем "б", которой нет в "8 у" - почему результат должен быть 16? === Возможно МойОфис не умеет работать с формулами массива.

Comment: `https://habr.com/ru/articles/672114/` - Похоже на кривой недоделанный продукт :)